# How can I disable caching for the volume in Windows 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012, cache, disk-cache

When I try to disable disk cache on Windows Server 2012, I get "windows could not change the write-caching setting for the device" error.

How do I disable the disk cache?

Comment: What is the name of the disk in device manager?

Comment: C: and D: - both volumes do not allow to disable cache.

Comment: @pauska or if you mean label - both are "Local disk"

Comment: No, in device manager there is a subgroup called "Disk drives". Like this, from my own workstation: https://ibb.co/dfpijT

Comment: @pauska LSI RAID 5/6 SAS 6G SCSI Disk Device

Comment: Actually, the caching is disabled now. O_O I don't understand how it happened.